# Interesting PL/SQL and Algorithmic analysis - trying to create a page

Tags: javascript, algorithm, graph, plsql, oracle-apex

I have the following issue which I'm not really sure how to tackle. I'm trying to do this in APEX, and combine PL/SQL with JavaScript, HTML, CSS.

I have:

- a list of raw materials with the duration of their production
- the list above includes also products made from the raw materials and the duration of the creating the products
- another list which is in fact a mapping that specifies what a product needs to be created (how many and which other products/raw materials)

My goal is to create a way where someone says that he needs N pieces of product X and it would tell the user what raw materials he would need to create and how many.

I'll give you an example:

```
SE,TX,SS are raw materials
D,FB are products

SE takes  1.2 hours to create
FB takes  1.8 hours to create
D  takes  2.7 hours to create
TX takes 10.8 hours to create
SS takes 14.4 hours to create

1 D = 1 FB + 1 SS
1 FB = 2 SE + 2 TX
------------------
1 D = (2 SE + 2 TX) + 1 SS

The user wants 4 D.
He would need to create 8 SE, 8 TX, 4 SS.
<em>It would take him (but this is <strong>OPTIONAL</strong>):</em>
(D) 2.7 + 
(SE,TX,SS) max(
               (SE,TX) max(1.2,10.8) = 10.8,
               (SS)                    14.4
              ) = 14.4 = 17.1 hours
```

What I've done so far is to build 2 tables.
The Items table, where 4,7,8 are raw materials and 23,37 are products.

```
ITEMS

ITEM_ID NAME    TIME
4       SE      1.2
7       TX      10.8
8       SS      14.4
23      FB      1.8
37      D       2.7
```

The Mapping table where I establish these relations:

```
1 D = 1 FB + 1 SS
1 FB = 2 SE + 2 TX
```

```
MAPPING

MAPPING_ID   TO_BUILD_ITEM_ID   REQ_ITEM_ID   NO_OF_REQ_ITEM_ID
22           23                 4             2
23           23                 7             2
52           37                 23            1
53           37                 8             1
```

I've also created a view that kind of adds everything together:

```
ID  TO_BUILD    ID_REQ  REQ NO_REQ  REQUIRED
4   SE          -       -   0       0x
7   TX          -       -   0       0x
8   SS          -       -   0       0x
23  FB          4       SE  2       2x SE
23  FB          7       TX  2       2x TX
37  D           8       SS  1       1x SS
37  D           23      FB  1       1x FB



CREATE OR REPLACE FORCE VIEW "BIG_MAPPING" 
("ID", "TO_BUILD", "ID_REQ", "REQ", "NO_REQ", "REQUIRED") AS 
  SELECT
  i1.ITEM_ID ID,
  i1.NAME TO_BUILD,
  i2.ITEM_ID ID_REQ,
  i2.NAME REQ,
  m.NO_OF_REQ_ITEM_ID NO_REQ,
  m.NO_OF_REQ_ITEM_ID || 'x ' || i2.NAME REQUIRED
FROM
  MAPPING m,
  ITEMS i1,
  ITEMS i2
WHERE
  m.TO_BUILD_ITEM_ID = i1.ITEM_ID (+)
  AND
  m.REQ_ITEM_ID = i2.ITEM_ID (+)

UNION

SELECT
  ITEM_ID,
  NAME,
  NULL,
  NULL,
  0,
  '0x '
FROM
  ITEMS
WHERE ITEM_ID IN (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11)
ORDER BY 1 ASC
```

I added that second SELECT as I thought I should add the "parents", so the raw materials don't have anything but their name and ID. The rest are NULL.

Now, what I've done so far is I've managed the following extraction:

```
SELECT 
  DISTINCT ID as ID,
  TO_BUILD,
  regexp_substr(SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH(NO_REQ, ','), '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL-1) as REQ,
  SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH(ID, ',') as SYS_CON, 
  LEVEL as LVL
FROM big_mapping
WHERE LEVEL > 1
START WITH ID= 37
CONNECT BY PRIOR ID_REQ = ID
ORDER BY SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH(ID, ',') ASC


ID  TO_BUILD    REQ SYS_CON    LVL
23  FB          1   ,37,23     2
4   SE          2   ,37,23,4   3
7   TX          2   ,37,23,7   3
8   SS          1   ,37,8      2
```

So basically I'm stuck here, because the last table above displays the path and an order of the operations. Just like when you would load a polynomial expression into a graph. And it does not display the main parent which is product "D" for which we are supposed to display the way it is built.

I don't know what to do further.. Is there anyway to calculate this in PL/SQL? If not, how do you suggest to do it?

To use that last code as a Cursor and load the findings in a JavaScript Array? If so, how should the Array be loaded? What would that structure be? And how should I proceed further?

Comment: Just guess (I haven't tested): remove `WHERE LEVEL > 1` from your last query (all other things look OK). If it will not help, could you please make an example in sqlfiddle.com?

Comment: @Dmitry - Removing the WHERE clause triggers an error "ORA-01428: argument '0' is out of range". I think it's much more than that in order to achieve what I want.

Comment: @Dmitry - I've tried to use sqlfiddle.com, but mysql doesn't support the CONNECT BY PRIOR clause.

Comment: sqlfiddle.com allows to choose different servers, oracle among of them (menu at the top of a page). Error - because of regexp_substr don't allow 0 as argument (when LEVEL = 0), but you can rewrite this expression. Could you describe what you want to do with regexp_substr?

Comment: Okay, didn't see that at sqlfiddle. With RegExp, to extract how many items I would need. That's what the column "REQ" is for. Again, I'm not sure if this is the right way to solve my problem. I've just started building things. I may require JavaScript or maybe another strategy in terms of the whole plan. Maybe I've started wrong. That's why I decided to post my question here.

Comment: `1 D = 1 FB + 1 SS;   1 FB = 2 SE + 2 TX;   1 D = (2 SE + 2 TX) + 1 SS`

See the similarity between the REQ column and the number of items (example: 2 SE) ?